# Awaiting the value of a promise without using the async await keywords?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, async-await

In my Angular HttpInterceptor class I'm implementing a refresh mechanism that detects when the JWT token is expired, and retrieves a new one from the backend. Once the new one is retrieved it overwrites the token in local storage, thus extending the expiration of the user's session.

Part of the HttpInterceptor's function is to log the user out of their session if it detects that the JWT expiry date has been reached.

However I am coming across a problem. After the request for the JWT has been sent out, it seems that another request is being sent out to the backend immediately after. Since the token is expired by this point, the API is returning a 403 and the interceptor is detecting this and kicking the user out the session before the response with the new JWT token has returned. This means that the user is being logged out before the token has had a chance to be refreshed.

Usually this wouldn't be an issue, as I could just use async/await to ensure that the new JWT is returned before any other request is made. However this will not work in the interceptor as it implements the `HttpInterceptor` interface, which means that if I attempt to use the `async` keyword on the `intercept` method that the interface implements, then I get a compiler error as the return type of the `intercept` method must be `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>` and cannot be `Promise<Observable<HttpEvent<T>>>`.

```
//The below violates the HttpInterceptor interface
async intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Promise<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>> { ... }

//The below violates the async keyword
async intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { ... }
```

My current code for the intercept method is below.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = this.addHeaders(req);

    if(req.headers.has("refreshTokenRequest")) {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(val => console.log("Interceptor handler, req to: " + req.url)));
    }

    if(localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")) {
      if(util.isJwtExpired("jwt_token")) {
        console.log("Jwt is expired, getting new token");
        this.getNewToken().then(newTokenResponse => {  //the .then() method needs to be awaited so that the expired JWT token can be overwritten before ANY other requests are sent
          this._authService.setAuthorizationToken(newTokenResponse.token);
          console.log("New token set");
          return this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next);
        });

      }
    }

    return this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next);
  }
```

So therefore I need a way to be able to await the returned value of the `this.getNewToken()` promise, without using the async/await keywords. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an observable from promise, and use `mergeMap` operator to merge the observables you want to return.

```
  import { from } from 'rxjs';
  import { tap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  ...

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = this.addHeaders(req);

    if(req.headers.has("refreshTokenRequest")) {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(val => console.log("Interceptor handler, req to: " + req.url)));
    }

    if(localStorage.getItem("jwt_token")) {
      if(util.isJwtExpired("jwt_token")) {
        console.log("Jwt is expired, getting new token");
        return from(this.getNewToken.call(this)).pipe(
          tap(newTokenResponse => {
            this._authService.setAuthorizationToken(newTokenResponse.token)
          }),
          mergeMap(() => this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next))
        )

      }
    }
    return this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next);
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain why I'd use mergemap rather than concatMap in this situation? I'd have thought I'd have wanted concatMap so that I can ensure the order of the observables would be maintained?

Comment: Also can you explain `.call(this)` in this line `this.getNewToken.call(this))`

Comment: @Jake12342134 There is no difference between in this case, because there is only once observable inside the operator

Comment: I am not sure the `this` keyword is used in your `getNewToken ` method, so i given `this` value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Is there not two? The first which is created by `fromPromise(this.getNewToken())` and the second returned by `this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next)` which returns `Observable<HttpEvent<Any>>`?

Comment: I mean the `handleRequestWithCatchError` method inside the `mergeMap` is only send the value once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200608/discussion-between-hsuan-lee-and-jake12342134).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use promises but rather observables.

Anyway, simply wrap it around a promise that you resolve when your data is loaded.

```
req = this.addHeaders(req);
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(req.headers.has("refreshTokenRequest")) {
  // Your code here
  }
})

return prom.then(v => this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next));
```

## EDIT

As [@mbojko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7194268/mbojko) pointed out, return an observable instead (like I've said first), because [the signature](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) doesn't accept promises.

```
return from(prom.then(v => this.handleRequestWithCatchError(req, next)));
```

Comment: In the intercept method? It'll be the same TS error.

Comment: `intercept` should return an observable, you're returning a promise.

Comment: @mbojko oh well, didn't pay attention, sorry for that ! resolving it right now.

Comment: @mbojko (TBH I just based my answer on his code, assuming it was working. Added the edit to my answer)